# Python urx 0.10.0 not returning get_digital_in(0,'nb')

Tags: python-3.x, socket.io

I am fairly new to python and urx.  I am attempting to control a universal robots ur-5 using python 3.6 with urx downloaded and installed.  The code I am using is below.

The communications are established, the robot makes the four moves and sets digital out zero to True.  I do not get an error but I can not find the return value for get_digital_in(0,'nb')

```
#robot_test1

import urx
from urx import urrobot

try:
    rob = urx.Robot("192.168.120.30")
    print("Connection Opened")
    rob.is_running()
    print("Robot is running")
    rob.is_program_running()
    print("Program Running")

    x = rob.get_digital_in(0,'nb')

    print(x)    
    print("digital Input is: "+str(x))
    rob.set_digital_out(0,True)

    print()

    print("Current tool pose is: ", rob.getl)

    rob.movej((0.5,0,0,0,0,0),1,1, relative = True)
    print("Move tool pose is: ", rob.getl)

    rob.movej((-0.5,0,0,0,0,0),1,1,relative = True)

    rob.up(0.1,1,1)
    rob.down(0.1,1,1)

except:
    print("Unexpected Error")

finally:
    rob.close()
    print("Closing Connection")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send commands to the robot but reading data from the robot through commands is difficult. Instead, once the port opens, the robot sends a packet of 1044 bytes which you can see in the excel file in this page [here](https://www.universal-robots.com/how-tos-and-faqs/how-to/ur-how-tos/remote-control-via-tcpip-16496/). The data received is Matlab data which you wont be able to read directly and so look at this [conversion](http://www.zacobria.com/universal-robots-knowledge-base-tech-support-forum-hints-tips/knowledge-base/client-interfaces-cartesian-matlab-data/) method.  The 86th packet of 8 bytes gives you the status of digital inputs (For software v3.0 and v3.1). Hope this helps.